# How to drive multiple floating N-channel MOSFETs

Tags: pwm, mosfet-driver, led-driver, dimming, floating

I want drive a RGBW-LED ([CREE XLamp XM-L](https://cree-led.com/products/xlamp-leds-arrays/xlamp-xm-l-color-gen2)) using a synchronous constant current buck. To control the brightness and color, the LED of each color channel is controlled by a shunt transistor using PWM.

The circuit is operated with a voltage of 24 V. Each LED has a forward current of 350 mA and a forward voltage of 3.3V. The buck converter has a switching frequency of 1 MHz. The PWM controller has a switching frequency of 20 kHz and a resolution of 8 bits.

[image: Schematic]

The buck converter and the PWM dimmer are implemented by a 5 V microcontroller. To allow the microcontroller to switch the high side (**SWITCH_H**) and low side switch (**SWITCH_L**) a dual MOSFET driver is used.

The control of the shunt transistors (**T_R, T_G, T_B, T_W**) is more difficult, because they are floating (the source connections of the transistors are on changing potentials).

**How can I drive the four N-channel MOSFET shunt transistors (**T_R, T_G, T_B, T_W**) using the 5 V microcontroller in a cost-effective and space-saving way?**

*My budget is around 3$. The footprint should not be much bigger than 2 cm x 2 cm.*

During my research on the Internet for a solution, I found only the [LT3965](https://www.analog.com/en/products/lt3965.html). However, this IC is much too expensive and therefore not an option for me. Unfortunately, I could not find any alternative products.

Comment: can you use a 24V/0V control signal for each?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? The initial situation is the PWM output of a 5V microcontroller. How exactly should I connect the 5V PWM outputs of the microcontroller to the gate inputs of the shunt transistors?

Comment: i mean can you convert it to a 24V PWM signal?

Comment: This could be an option. However, this would have the disadvantage that the gate voltage of the transistors can vary greatly. E.g. if T_G, T_B and T_W are switched on first, the gate source voltage at T_R would be a little less than 24V. On the other hand, if T_G, T_B and T_W are turned off, the gate source voltage at T_R would be about 14V. The question is how exactly the circuit would look like and if it would work despite the large variations of the gate source voltage.

Comment: Yes, so that depends on whether an unknown voltage between 14V and 24V is good enough for your circuit.

Comment: Good luck driving your Nch FETS on the high side . There are much better ways with Pch and open drain or collector gate drivers  Have you looked for any series LED driver IC's or are you trying to reinvent the wheel?  Why not drive all from your 3.3V Vdd on uC with Nch. This is not a practical solution or even a well defined problem  Do you understand the thermodynamics of putting > 3W on a 2x2 cm board? The LED needs at about 10 sq cm 2oz copper per W . Many things to learn before you try this.

Comment: I have difficulty understanding your answers. Maybe you could explain your ideas a little more. Simply writing "open drain" or "open collector" is not very helpful.

Comment: What makes you think that I want to release 3W on a 2cm x 2xm area? In my question I only said that the drivers for the shunt transistors should fit approximately on this surface.

Comment: N-channel mosfets are more efficient, because of lower RDSon. I am by no means reinventing the wheel. For example, my approach is described in this paper by Analog (https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/technical-articles/P371_EN-Matrix.pdf).

Comment: @Michael you cannot use the MCP14A0304 or similar gate driver for your buck converter. The MCP part is a low-side gate driver. When the high-side mosfet is on, the source will be at almost 24V. The MCP can only drive the gate voltage up to the maximum supply voltage of 18V. You need to drive the gate voltage higher than the supply voltage in order to turn the mosfet on. You can use high side gate drivers for this (FAN5109MX is an example, although it will not work in this case). Notice the use of a bootstrap circuit. This may also be the solution for driving your series mosfets :)

Comment: Very interesting driving scheme! If you hadn't published it, it could have been patentable. Are you planning on adjusting the duty cycle to handle the difference in Vf by different bypassing options? How wide dimming can you manage? I'm thinking close to zero would be a challenge.

Comment: Interesting ?,  The Op wants to replicate the design of the LT3965-1 for $3 without any experience or R&D budget yet the IC costs $10 in 500 pc volume, if you do not know what an open collector is, you aren't ready to design analog. Let me repeat, this is a poorly defined problem, but here's your solution https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUCLc.png  Is this where you got the idea?

Answer (score 3):

The only gate potentials for M1...M4 guaranteed to be significantly higher or lower than the corresponding source are 0V or 24V, so those are the potentials you must apply to the gates.

It's easy to do with simple common source N-channel MOSFETs (M5 to M8 below), each with a resistor (R5 to R8) to pull up drain potential to +24V when the transistor is off. When the MOSFET's gate is high, +5V, its drain is pulled low, and the corresponding transistor across the LED is switched off.

Beware, there's a chance you might exceed the maximum \$V_{GS}\$ permissible for M1...M4 (commonly that's 20V), so use devices able to tolerate \$V_{GS}=24V\$, or find some way to protect them.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi72yO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

[image: enter image description [here][1]] [(1)](https://www.digikey.ca/-/media/Images/Product%20Highlights/L/Linear%20Technology/LT3965%208%20Switch%20LED%20Dimmer/matrix-led-dimmer-powered-by-a-buck-mode-led-driver-1.jpg?la=en&ts=5ba4a685-b8ed-4034-ab48-06edba77999c)

Pour s'amuser.

[image]

*Quick N dirty design.*

My 3.3V version has a lower average but higher peak power by not sharing current. 2~3W avg, 5Wpk @ 3.3V using Vf nom.
The series version uses constant = average power 4W @ 12V